# is there a short way to write ? value !== null

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, boolean

I have `value !== null`

I need to get false in null case but 0 is true.
is there a short way to write?

`!!value` or `Boolean(value)` not works for me.

Comment: show entire piece of code please

Comment: There is ?? operator. You can just specify `value ?? false` and when the value is `null` it will evaluate to `false`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: @g_1_k that does not return a boolean if `value` is `0`

Comment: Is this about programming or code golfing? `value !== null` is simple and unambiguous. What's the problem with it?

Comment: @AlbertoChiesa which one is simple ```value !== undefined``` ? or ```!!value``` ?  i just wanted to find the simple way like this to make more simple and short code

Comment: @GaroGabrielyan it's not about supposed simplicity. It's about making correct and robust code. `!!` will handle falsy values (`0`, `''` and `false`) in the same way of `null` and `undefined`. Personally I prefer `!= null` (with only one equal instead of two) because in my code I tend to treat `null` and `undefined` in the same way (usually excluding them from the main code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `!=` instead of `!==` if you also want to return `false` for the input `undefined`. And you can omit the spaces around the operator:

```
value!=null
```

Short of a helper function `isNull(…)`, it won't get any shorter. There is no special "null test" unary operator, if that is what you were looking for.